# Android studio - unknown hax vcpu error for virtual devices, how do i fix this?

Tags: android

When trying to run any android virtual device I get the error "unknown hax vcpu return 1" and then the device closes, how do i fix this?

Comment: Though this does not necessarily answer your question, you can always download the Genymotion emulator for android. I've found that it works much much faster than the android studio emulators in both boot up time and actual performance. You can download it/find more info on their website genymotion.com

Answer (score 0):

Restarting computer did the trick. 
Taken from [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=201694)