# Android Studio Emulator crashing on Mac (non-specific error log, strange sounds from monitor). Uninstall devices?

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, android-emulator

I was working in Android Studio, and I've been having problems with the emulated devices shutting themselves down properly, causing me to have to Force Quit them and start another device emulation.  When that happens, Android Studio still registers the emulator as connected and running.

In the process of testing my app, I accidentally tried to run the app on one of the emulators I had Force Quit earlier, and this caused Android Studio to freeze completely.  I had no choice but to Force Quit the entirety of Android Studio.  After restarting the app, everything was slow and mostly unresponsive, so I decided to restart my Mac.

After that, Android studio runs fine as it should, but none of my emulators will run.  I start the emulator, then this weird rhythmic static sound starts coming out of my second monitor until I turn it off and turn it back on.  The emulator crashes, OS X throws up an error asking if I want to reopen it, and the log spits out some unspecified cpu error.

So obviously the Force Quit that I was forced to do earlier today really messed things up, because I've never had this problem before.  I've seen lots of different answers to similar problems, but I don't want to get rid of more than I have to.  I tried uninstalling Android Studio the usual way (deleting the app), and then reinstalling, but that didn't change anything.

There are lots of things about how to remove the 'deeper' elements of the app, but I'm not sure what the end result will be, or what exactly I should do to fix this specific problem.  Is there a way to rebuild/reinstall the emulators without getting rid of anything else?  One answer had terminal instructions on how to do this, but it also wipes the keystore.

I already have an app in the Play store, and I don't want to mess up anything.  I do have the .jks file in with my app files, but I'm not sure exactly what will happen if I follow the instructions in the answers I've seen already.

Any help would be much appreciated, because my work is at a stand-still now until I can get these emulators/simulators running again.

Comment: I went through all the reinstallation procedures and everything else that was outlined, and I thought it worked.  I just went to start an emulator after re-downloading and re-installing it all...and it goes right back to doing the same thing--weird static on the second monitor, and then the simulator crashes.  Same errors and everything.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the last months I had a few occasions where my emulators were misbehaving, they would consume a lot of CPU while doing nothing. However I don't have a second monitor and I didn't hear anything.

The way I checked was opening a terminal and running `top`, but you may do that in different ways as well. Once I found the offending process pid I killed it from terminal and my iMac got responsive again. Opening the same emulator again was ok.

There were also other occasions when I had emulators not running apps properly. The solution here was deleting that emulator and creating a new one with the same configuration, which usually works for me. That happened a lot when google started releasing the first android N previews, although I didn't use any N emulator back then.

Another step further is cleaning the android sdk manager, that's the guy who downloads/updates things like emulator images and sdk versions for you. Open Android Studio, click on SDK manager, click on "Launch Standalone SDK Manager". A new window shouod pop up, and you can see the path where it's installed at the top. In case you want to wipe it out just open finder on that path, delete everything and download a new SDK Manager from google. BTW I always download this before Android Studio and keep it in a separate path. Remember to close and reopen Android Studio, and when it complains about not finding the SDK manager gently show it where it is.

Comment: I was checking if you can delete things from SDK manager and in fact it is possible. You can try selecting the bad emulator's system image there and then click the delete button, and try downloading them again. I wouldn't expect this to fix the problem, but it's another step that may be helpful troubleshooting it. BTW I forgot to ask if you're using the latest stable version of Android Studio, emulators, tools and platform tools, and OSX?

Comment: I am on the latest everything for Android Studio, and I'm on OS X 10.11.2.  I will try these and report back if the problem has been fixed.  I forgot to add that I also tried creating a new emulator from scratch with a totally different device, and it didn't do anything different.  None of the emulators work, in any configuration.  It's as if the manager itself is corrupted.  Thanks for the suggestions!  I really appreciate the timely response.

Comment: I got the manager corrupted in more than one occasion, and a co-worker had a really bad time making it work when he got a new computer. We don't  know how we fixed it and it may be a coincidence, but when it worked we had it downloaded separately from AS and installed in a different place like $HOME/bin. If you try doing that try also running the emulator from command line and see if there's any difference. And double check `java -version`, I always stick to Oracle 1.8 BTW.

Comment: After I get this all taken care of, I will definitely try putting the manager in a different place.  I'm doing some other things right now so I apologize for my delays, but my java -version output in terminal is java version "1.7.0_79"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_79-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode).  I'm going through your first suggestions now, and I will update with the end result either way.  I'll try running top in terminal first to see if I catch anything weird.  Thanks again.

Comment: Using top, I saw the qemu_system process jump over 107% on the CPU usage, and then it terminates itself, OS X throws up the usual error, and the log inside of AS shows 'Unknown hax vcpu return 1'.

Comment: I just ended up wiping everything inside the sdk folder.  I'll try reinstalling and if it works, I'll mark this as answered.  I appreciate all the help.  :)

Comment: EDIT Found it I think.

Comment: And I'm back to square one after all of that.  The same thing just happened.  I have no idea what the deal is.

Comment: That hax message is very important, you should focus on that. Did you install "intel x86 emulator accelerator" from sdk manager? This other user has the same problem as you, you may start watching that problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37886312/android-studio-unknown-hax-vcpu-error-for-virtual-devices-how-do-i-fix-this

Comment: I did have that installed on the first reinstall, but I'm in the middle of doing a second one now with the SDK in a non-standard location.  I'll be keeping tabs on both posts from here on out.  I've also thought about trying out a previous Time Machine backup of the SDK directory, but I'm going to finish this second reinstall first to see if anything is different.  Thanks for the help so far.  I appreciate it.

Comment: I reinstalled everything twice now, and nothing has changed.  This is what it says in the log every time:  emulator: WARNING: VM heap size set below hardware specified minimum of 128MB
emulator: WARNING: Setting VM heap size to 384MB
Hax is enabled
Hax ram_size 0x60000000
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
console on port 5554, ADB on port 5555
Unknown hax vcpu return 1

Comment: Hmm I don't remember running this, but some people report that you have to go into [sdk manager folder]/extras/intel/Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager/IntelHAXM_6.0.1.dmg and run it manually. Apparently there's also an installer script there. Other people report that you must go into BIOS settings and enable virtualization but... do Macs have BIOS access?

Comment: My logs are similar but working: > emulator @Nexus_6P_API_23
emulator: WARNING: VM heap size set below hardware specified minimum of 384MB
emulator: WARNING: Setting VM heap size to 384MB
Hax is enabled
Hax ram_size 0x60000000
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
console on port 5554, ADB on port 5555
Your emulator is out of date, please . . .

Comment: I just wanted to pop back in and say, long story short, I had to reinstall OS X because my Mac decided it no longer wanted to boot.  Since I've restored from my Time Machine backup, I didn't lose any work.  I have since switched to Genymotion for now just to avoid any further problems.  I appreciate all of the help.  Perhaps my boot file corruption had something to do with my issues.  The HDD itself is fine physically.

Comment: I'm still curious whether the emulator started working again, pls let me know if you ever try it. BTW there's this command that seems to check your HW acceleration `emulator-check accel`.

Comment: I happened to accidentally start the normal emulator instead of Genymotion and it worked just fine.  No weird sounds or anything like that.  Something really messed up my file system I suppose.  I'm still having problems with my cloud services, but that's unrelated to this post.  At least I can work again.  Thanks for all your help.